# Root Cause for ClientAbortException for tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, apache, sockets, tomcat, restlet-2.0

I have a set for staging server with Apache configured on one machine and my setup for application and web-service hosted on other machine with two separate tomcat 6.0 instances . The App was working perfectly since last 6 month however i am facing following error since last 1 week . I am using Restlet2.0 for web service implementation . Please help me with the Root Cause for this or situations where this error can arise .

```
    Nov 21, 2013 6:30:16 PM com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter commit
    SEVERE: An exception occured writing the response entity
    ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:278)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
        at org.restlet.resource.StringRepresentation.write(StringRepresentation.java:211)
        at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.writeResponseBody(HttpServerCall.java:492)
        at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.sendResponse(HttpServerCall.java:428)
        at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletCall.sendResponse(ServletCall.java:421)
        at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter.commit(HttpServerConverter.java:392)
        at com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:148)
        at com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:881)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:299)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:981)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:314)
        ... 25 more
```